# apache2 virtual hosts not working after macports install php55

Tags: php, macos, apache, virtualhost, macports

I will try to be as descriptive as posible. I had apache2 php53 and mysql installed on osx lion via macports and everything was working fine, today I installed php55 using macports and selected php55 through macports as the php version to use, I restarted apache and none of my virtual hosts work, however if I navigate to http:// localhost/index.php it works. I tried switching back to php53 and now virtual hosts dont work either, where as before that was my configuration and was working fine. Any ideas? I have been searching all day long before asking here and did not really find any answers. Should I paste my httpd.conf or phpinfo or vhosts here? would that be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this. After a whole day looking through all the config files for apache and php, I replaced this piece of code on httpd.conf

Listen 80

to

Listen 127.0.0.1:80

not sure why this happened but this fixed the problem for me and hope it is helpful for anybody that runs through the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This page might have some answers:

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP

Or try the MacPorts mailing list.